# Process PointerWheelChanged event with GestureRecognizer

Tags: c#, uwp, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UWP App, where I want to handle `ManipulationDelta` or `ManipulationUpdated` and `ManipulationCompleted` on `PointerWheelChanged` event(to handle horizontal scroll from mouse or touchPad).

On `PointerwheelChanged` event, i have managed this with

```
gesture.ProcessMouseWheelEvent(e.GetCurrentPoint(this), false,false);
```

where `e` is `PointerRoutedEventArgs`.

Code Snippet:

```
GestureRecognizer gesture = new GestureRecognizer();
gesture.ManipulationCompleted += OnManipulationCompleted;
gesture.ManipulationUpdated += OnManipulationUpdated;

 void OnManipulationUpdated(object sender, ManipulationUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
 //Ideally this Should be called whenever there is a change in manipulation
}

void OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    //Code for Scroll
//Ideally this has to be called on completion of Manipulation Event(Correct me if am wrong)
    }


 private void onPointerwheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
 gesture.ProcessMouseWheelEvent(e.GetIntermediatePoints((this) sender)[0], false, false);
}
```

The Problem with this Approach is, whenever onPointerwheelChanged event is fired , `ManipulationCompleted` is too fired, despite myself performing a single long slide in TouchPad(Finger was in contact with touch pad whole through the slide).

Ideally only one `ManipulationCompleted` event should be triggered at the end of the single long slide. But multiple `ManipulationCompleted` events are getting Triggered.

Is there a way out of this?
Making `GestureRecognizer` to fire `ManipulationCompleted` Event only at the end of slide?

Comment: Hi there! Excellent question. Can you please include your code so we can see more specifically what is happening? We can't debug without it. Thanks

Comment: You need to add your code to your question. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you need more information on how to ask a question that people will answer

Comment: What kind of manipulation are you using? Could you post some codes about your Xaml and the Transforms you are using? Or maybe a basic demo can also help.

Comment: Am using GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateX and GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateInertia. In Xaml, i have a grid which has to be moved with its PointerWheelChanged Event. On PointerWheelChanged Event, am calling gesture.ProcessMouseWheelEvent. Is there a way to get a series of ManipulationUpdated events and finally a single ManipulationCompleted with GestureRecognizer on a Single Slide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whenever `onPointerwheelChanged` event is fired , `ManipulationCompleted` is too fired

It is an expected behavior. According to [PointerWheelChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerwheelchanged.aspx):

> If the element where pointer events occur has a non-default ManipulationMode value, then the action might also result in various manipulation events like ManipulationStarted.

The reason of this behaviour is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.pointerpointproperties.mousewheeldelta.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> The mouse wheel button has discrete, evenly spaced notches or distance thresholds (also called detents). When you rotate or tilt the wheel, a wheel message is sent as each detent is encountered.

So, if you want to handle something when the user finished rotating the mouse wheel. I suggest you following one of the options below:

1. If you want to show some data of the event(e.g. the position of the grid). Update it each time the `ManipulationCompleted` event triggered. Thus, user will see the real-time data.
2. You can set a state for boundary point(e.g. `bool gridHitBoundary=false`). In `OnManipulationUpdated` update the state when the boundary point has been hit, and run logic in `ManipulationCompleted` when `gridHitBoundary==true`.

Comment: I Wana implement Infinite Scroll, So No Boundaries! Anyhow..thanks for d Answer!